# Changing parameters in Arduino without the IDE

Tags: isp

I’m installing Arduino-based well monitors in my local community.  Each well is different and has slightly different parameters and several hardware variations.  Currently, when I need to make a program change I have to uninstall the Arduino, bring it back to my computer, reprogram it, then reinstall it.  I’m developing these units as I go so there are various refinements that arise as well. I’d love to be able to reprogram a unit in place.  It seems like it *could* be done with another Arduino but I don’t currently have the skills for that.  The second, less flexible, method would be to use dip switches to select various options.  This option is attractive but would limit me to only the options that I know of at programming time.  Is there a third option I haven’t thought of?  Has anyone else tried programming one Arduino from the other?
Edit: I’m primarily using Unos but I’m working on a low power version that will use a Mini Pro. The units are accessible as far as USB cables and such. However I don’t own a laptop.

Comment: Please tell us what arduino board you use. Can you connect a (usb) cable to it? Can you connect a laptop to the arduino without removing it from the well? Perhaps you can write a command line interface and store values in eeprom. Then you can connect a laptop to the arduino and change values. Update your question with the extra information please.

Comment: You could maybe adapt this: https://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader

Comment: i would use an esp8266's SPIFFS to store the config; then you can program it from your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a Standalone programmer. I offer one, it loads the target device from a program you select on SD card.  Up to 256 programs can be stored on 1 card. 
Check it out here  www.crossroadsfencing.com/BobuinoRev17/Programmer.html